# How to explode 1 string into 2 variables after \n (new line). php

Tags: php, string, variables, explode

I have a string:

```
$str1 = 123\n123;
```

How to explode this string into 2 variables after first \n?

So, result for 123\n123 should be:

```
$strFirstLine = 123;
$strSecondLine = 123;
```

for 123\n123\n123 should be:

```
$strFirstLine = 123;
$strSecondLine = 123 123;
```

e.g. everything after first \n should go to 2nd variable.

Comment: use the limit parameter `explode("\n", $str, 2);`

Comment: `$str1 = 123\n123;` - please post your actual syntax. That should error out `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting ',' or ';'...`

Comment: @DarkBee thanks! Thats excactly what I need (: You can answer and i'll pick it as solution!

Answer (score -1):

Give 2 as the third argument so that it splits the string into 2 parts only:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $str1, 2);
$strFirstLine = $arr[0];
$strSecondLine = $arr[1];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$str1 = 123\n123;
$pieces = explode("\n", $str1);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Comment: Do you realize what that will produce? Run it yourself and you'll see. I know you pasted what the OP posted in their question, to which I posted [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918092/how-to-explode-1-string-into-2-variables-after-n-new-line-php#comment74869488_43918092) about that, yet they did not respond to it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.